# how find out whether a change is made from UI or from console in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a complex Ruby on rails application. 
So end users can make changes from th Ui, where as developers can also make changes from the console. 
So is there a way to find out whether the change was made from UI or console. 
I can capture the end users login details when they make changes from UI but what can I do to know who made changes from the console?
Please help?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is NO, changes from console cannot be traced or tracked. Access to console means access to the whole application with no locks.

Answer (score 1):

When a user has access to rails c he usually has the application in his hands unrestricted. So I am pessimistic in that regard.

You could try to implement/use a restricted console, which implements a current_user method depending on the login on the applications machine. But that might be a bit far fetched for your scenario?

**Update:** Well...this "roll your own" might be simpler than I thought at first. Of course you can implement an initializer like e.g. current_console_user.rb

```
module Test3ElementBase
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.current_console_user=ENV["USER"] if ENV["RAILS_CONSOLE"] == "Y"
  end
end
```

Then wrap the console call tightly into

```
RAILS_CONSOLE=Y rails c
```

Now Test3ElementBase::Application.config.current_console_user is only defined, when called from console. You now "only" have to mix this fact into your original current_user method.

Of course there might be much simpler ways, I'm just a nub :-)

Comment: Yes i do have current_user method but the current user method gets set only when the user enter his or her credentials from Ui and logs into the application. How can i do something like that from console.

I need to capture the details of changes made by people from console also for security purposes.

Comment: As I said: You have to implement your own console or find some existing implementation. Such a user restricted console would make sense, but I dont know of any such app.

Comment: I'll look into. Appreciate the help :)